# Motivation to reformulate General Relativity in terms of connections?

Tags: einstein, gravity

My understanding that is Einstein and Schrodinger both were in correspondence (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03ReIvXKrrU)) and looking to reformulate General Relativity in terms of connections (which lead to this [debacle](https://www.salon.com/2015/04/18/albert_is_an_old_fool_einstein_vs_schrodinger_in_battle_of_the_nobel_laureates/)). Now, from the viewpoint of quantum gravity this is extremely useful. But I suspect that this could not have been their motivation given their odds with the theory. Is there any historical record or otherwise on what motivated them to look for this theory?

Comment: Before 1950s, the only notions of connection in differential geometry were Cartan's and Ehresmann's, both hard to use. Koszul's notion of affine connections, widely used in Riemannian and semi-Riemannian geometry was introduced in mid 1950s, not as a replacement of metrics, but as a highly valuable enhancement. What is the evidence that either Einstein or Schrodinger understood one of the notion of connections?

Comment: @MoisheKohan this physicist claims so: https://youtu.be/03ReIvXKrrU

Comment: You should edit your question to include all available information, including the name and the exact quote. Personally, I do not trust YouTube videos.

Comment: @MoisheKohan neither do I but I do trust the founder of Loop Quantum Gravity.